# virtual path provider in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application i read static pages from database but at the same time normal asp.net pages also hitting the database.so it will take more time to load the pages.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i am new in asp.net,my web pages taking more time to loading the pages,i checked what is the problem through debug mode..in virtualpathprovider.cs->FileExists method it checked all the pages in database whether the file exists or not(.aspx,.ascx,etc..)so how to avoid these..

Comment: Show your code. And review http://stackoverflow.com/faq about how you should ask questions. Being a newbie in asp.net does not excuse a lack  of information in your question.